# How to translate the pro- prefix from English?

Tags: word-choice

In English you can say *pro-whatever* to say that you are in favour of something, such as *pro-independence*. I sometimes see people use the same prefix in Esperanto such as in *mi estas pro-eŭropa*. This seems wrong to me because the preposition *pro* has a different meaning in Esperanto. Is there a different prefix you could use for this? Maybe *por-eŭropa*? Or is it better to make an explicit sentence?

Answer (score 8):

I believe Por would be the correct answer

"Poreŭropa" would be the way to express "Pro-european"

https://adventuresinesperanto.wordpress.com/tag/por/

Comment: "Por-esperanta" and "kontraŭ-esperanta' are common enough. Also see the definition of por (as a prefix) in PIV.

Comment: For which, see http://vortaro.net/#por

Comment: Yes, _por_. The PIV article for [_pro_](http://vortaro.net/#pro) contains a remark with some examples about the differences of _por_ and _pro_.